# Compare value between current date and yesterday on the same table POSTGRESQL

Tags: database, postgresql, report

I have a table like this:

| product | value | trx_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 100 | 2020-06-01 |
| apple | 300 | 2020-06-02 |
| apple | 500 | 2020-06-03 |

and I need create a report like this (let's say today is 2020-06-03)

| product | yesterday | current_date | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 300 | 500 | 200 |

I'm confused how to create a query (PostgreSQL), comparing those values. fyi, i always update this table every day. I tried with `('1 day'::interval)` query but it always shows all dates before 2020-06-03 which is 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-02...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE product_table (product varchar, value integer, trx_date date);
INSERT INTO product_table values ('apple', 100, '06/01/2020'), ('apple', 300, '06/02/2020'), ('apple', 500, '06/03/2020');

WITH prev AS (
    SELECT
        product,
        value
    FROM
        product_table
    WHERE
        trx_date = '06/03/2020'::date - '1 day'::interval
)
SELECT
    pt.product,
    prev.value AS yesterday,
    pt.value AS CURRENT_DATE,
    pt.value - prev.value AS delta
FROM
    product_table AS pt,
    prev
WHERE
    trx_date = '06/03/2020';

 product | yesterday | current_date | delta 
---------+-----------+--------------+-------
 apple   |       300 |          500 |   200
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) lead or lag to 'combine' data to the current row from following rows (lead) or previous rows (lag). In this case the I use the lag function to get "yesterdays" value.

```
select product, yesterday,  today, today-yesterday delta
  from ( select p.product, p.value today 
              , lag(value) over (partition by p.product 
                                     order by p.trx_date) yesterday
              , p.trx_date
          from products p
       ) d
 where trx_date = '2020-06-03'::date ;
```